# Display text in UITextField

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield

I'm creating a lottery game using storyboard and when first opened displays the balance of player = 10 and the balance of the jackpot = 10.  However when I run the game nothing is displayed in either UITextField.  What am I missing or do I need to create a method for the each amount to be displayed in? and if I do how because I've tried that and I've had no luck?

```
- (id) init

{
    self = [super init];


if (self)
{
    NSInteger balance = 10;
    NSInteger jackpot = 10;

    txtBalance.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", balance];
    txtPot.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", jackpot];

}

return self;
}
```

Comment: Try to put some value using storyboard and comment out your code here.

Comment: Try putting your code inside `viewDidLoad` instead of `init`.

Comment: Thanks @AkshatSinghal. I knew that, it's just been a while since I've messed with storyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Run a test, debug or log `txtBalance` in your `init` method and you should see that it is `nil`, because the views haven't been loaded yet (assuming that this `init` method is in a view controller). Of course, the `init` method might not be called at all...

Generally, you want to move your code to a method that is called later, like `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear:`.